# Dictionary to List in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this python dictionary:

```
{'1000123456': ['Rubble', 100, 90, 80, 80, 87.5], '1000123454': ['Tom', 70, 0, 65, 95, 57.5], '1000123459': ['Chipmunk', 86, 70, 0, 96, 63.0]}
```

How can I convert above dictionary without any import exactly to below list:

```
[[1000123456, 'Rubble', 100, 90, 80, 80, 87.5], [1000123454, 'Tom', 70, 0, 65, 95, 57.5], [1000123459, 'Chipmunk', 86, 70, 0, 96, 63.0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zondo has given perfect and optimized answer. But still I would like to give simple answer for new python users:

```
final = []
for k,v in (dict.items()) :
        v.insert(0,k)
        final.append(v)
print final
```

In this program, I am trying to get key,value from dictionary for each iteration of for loop and inserting it into 'value' list since value is of type list. At the end, appending the value list to final list. The final list will have values like this:

```
  [['1000123456', 'Rubble', 100, 90, 80, 80, 87.5], ['1000123454', 'Tom', 70, 0, 65, 95, 57.5], ['1000123459', 'Chipmunk', 86, 70, 0, 96, 63.0]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a list comprehension:

```
items = [[int(k)]+v for k, v in dictionary.items()]
```

`[int(k)]` creates a list containing a single item: the key converted to an integer.  I then add the value to it, so it ends up being a list containing the key and all of the items in the value for each key-value pair in `dictionary`.

Comment: I'm curious. Would + or `extend` be more efficient here, for `[int(k)]+v`

Comment: @idjaw: For `+`: `1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 usec per loop`.  For `extend`: `1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 usec per loop`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for doing the analysis. So they are extremely close together. Good to know! :)

Comment: I dont think `extend` would actually work ... since it doesnt return anything .... (well it would work but items would just be a list of `[None,...]`

Comment: @zondo. Thanks for your reply. In your reply in this question page "How to reverse a dictionary in Python?", we just first make lower case for keys and values, then reverse. Can you guide me for make lower all keys and values? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah.  In `newdict.setdefault(string, []).append(key)`, change it to `newdict.setdefault(string.lower(), []).append(key.lower())`

Comment: only a lower at the end, i focused on input dictionary. Thanks a lot @zondo.
I have another error in my function, when I can't resolve, come here again ;)